# VBA Clear cell names in range

Tags: vba, excel

I need to clear the names of all named cells within a range before executing a procedure.

I've tried the following code with no success so far:

```
Sub EraseCellNames()

Worksheets("SheetA").Range("A1:G5").Select
Dim nName As Name
    For Each nName In Names
        If Not Intersect(Selection, Range(nName.Name)) Is Nothing Then
            nName.Delete
        End If
    Next nName

End Sub
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
Sub EraseCellNames()
    Dim nName As Name
    Dim targetRng As Range

    Set targetRng = Worksheets("SheetA").Range("A1:G5")

    For Each nName In ThisWorkbook.Names
        If nName.ValidWorkbookParameter Then
            If targetRng.Parent.Name = nName.RefersToRange.Parent.Name Then
                If Not Intersect(targetRng, nName.RefersToRange) Is Nothing Then nName.Delete
            End If
        End If
    Next nName
End Sub
```

Comment: There's no syntax error but the cell names are still the same after the procedure is executed, they're not deleted...

Comment: Can you show your workbook? I've tested this code and it works fine for me

Comment: What I meant when I said "clear the names of all named cells within a range" is the same as opening the Names Manager in the Formulas tab, choosing a defined name and deleting it, but for a specific range (A1:G5 in Sheet A).

Comment: It worked for another workbook with similar information (but no formulas on the cells - I dunno if there's any relation between what's in the cells and their names), but it doesn't work for the workbook I need. Unfortunately I can't upload the file as it is company-related stuff.

Comment: can you show your formula in cell and how your named ranges are organized (is it just direct reference to cell or some kind of `Offset`, `Indirect`)?

Comment: I used Indirect formulas to bring info from other sheets based on column label references and the other code I use name ranges based on Offset...

Comment: as I see from image above your cell is `D6` - in row №6, but you use `Set targetRng = Worksheets("SheetA").Range("A1:G5")` - only five rows - maybe there is an issue?

Comment: I used Worksheets("SheetA").Range("A1:G5") just as an exemple. I tried using Set targetRng = Worksheets("Sumário Aplicações").Range("C6:G6") for the code but it didn't work.